# svyrepdesign and svyglm error "all variables must be in design argument"

Tags: r, survey

When working with complex survey data, I am using this R statement to apply weights to observations in the data set.

I am encountering a message error: all vars must be included in the argument when running a generalized linear model using svyglm

If variables are added to the data set (data_covid) later, does the svrepdesign (design1) get updated with new variables added after svrepdesign has been set?

```
    design1 <- svrepdesign(
    weights = ~CPWWWGT, 
    repweights = "CPWW[001-100]+",
    type = "Fay",
    rho = 0.3,
    data = data_covid,
    combined.weights = TRUE
    )


   Error in svyglm.survey.design (number_symptoms ~ age, design = design1, : all 
   variables must be in design= argument
```

Comment: Make sure `number_symptoms` and `age` are in `data_covid` and spelled correctly

Comment: hi, answering your question: no, so it makes sense you'd get this error..  perhaps make your recodes then run the svrepdesign() command immediately before running the svyglm() ?

Answer (score 0):

> If variables are added to the data set (data_covid) later, does the
> svrepdesign (design1) get updated with new variables added after
> svrepdesign has been set?

Nope.  You need to either add them before you create the design object or create them inside the design object using the `update` function, eg

```
data(api)
dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat,
fpc=~fpc)
dstrat<-update(dstrat, apidiff=api00-api99)
```

If you want to check whether a variable is in the design object, use the `colnames` function, eg,

```
> colnames(dclus1)
 [1] "cds"      "stype"    "name"     "sname"    "snum"     "dname"    "dnum"    
 [8] "cname"    "cnum"     "flag"     "pcttest"  "api00"    "api99"    "target"  
[15] "growth"   "sch.wide" "comp.imp" "both"     "awards"   "meals"    "ell"     
[22] "yr.rnd"   "mobility" "acs.k3"   "acs.46"   "acs.core" "pct.resp" "not.hsg" 
[29] "hsg"      "some.col" "col.grad" "grad.sch" "avg.ed"   "full"     "emer"    
[36] "enroll"   "api.stu"  "fpc"      "pw"
```